# How to show commits on the top of this tag

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've TortoiseGit 2.4.0.0 installed. 
I've several commits after v1.64.3-src but how see them graphically?

I'm unable to find any way.

[image]

Comment: I've updated it to 2.6 but it works the same way

Answer (score 1):

The revision graph (as of TortoiseGit 2.6) only shows tags and branches - not single commits.

That's by design.

---

If you want to see all commits you have to use the log dialog.

In order to see all commits, open the log dialog (on the repository root or check "whole project" in the lower left) and then select "All Branches".

Then, all commits in the repository are shown. Now you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select the tag you are interested in. Then you can go up the commits (if you have lots of merges, you might find it comfortable to select "Parent 1" in the upper right combobox and then use the up arrow).

This quite long way is needed, as we cannot easily filter for the latest branch where the tag is on. If you know that (or can guess it by using the log dialog and select "Show branches this commit is on" on the context menu of the tagged commit), you can easily filter for that branch by clicking on the branch indicator on the upper left.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

[image: TortoiseGit Log dialog]

Comment: how to see latest commits in each branch graphically?

Answer (score 0):

> I've several commits after v1.64.3-src

If you have several commits after that tag, then you must have some ref. to keep them.
For example, the `maintain_v1.64` branch in the following figure:
[image]

As you can see, it shows some information of top commit when mouse hovers it.

> how see them graphically

You can right click on that branch, and click `Show Log`:
[image]

Then, shows:
[image]